# How to transfer db file over tcpip?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, rest, transfer-encoding

I have created wcf restful call which I am using for transfering notmal text file.

What is the possibile formate that I can user to have it transfer over tcpip?

I have tried reading it into the text formate but not able to get it in the reading formate so I want to keep as .db file after saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Practice for File Transfers are Byte Arrays ( byte[] ) or Base64 Strings.

But in a WCF environment you have to watch the size of your file.
If your file is growing at any time than you have to be sure that its lower as your Buffer Sizes in your WCF Host / Client. (MaxReceivedSendMessage,... => Buffer Sizes in Config File).